# pyspark Sortby didn't work on multiple values?

Tags: pyspark

Suppose I have rdd contain data of 4 tuples (a,b,c,d) in which that  a,b,c,and d are all integer variable

I'm try to sort data on assending order based on only d variable ( but it not finalized so I try to do something else )
This is current code I type

```
sortedRDD = RDD.sortBy(lambda (a, b, c, d): d)
```

however I check the finalize data but it seem that the result is still not corrected

```
# I check with this code
sortedRDD.takeOrdered(15)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the sorting order again in `takeOrdered`:

```
RDD.takeOrdered(15, lambda (a, b, c, d): d)
```

As you do not collect the data after the sort, the order is not guaranteed in subsequent operations, see the example below:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(1,2,3,4),(5,6,7,3),(9,10,11,2),(12,13,14,1)])
result = rdd.sortBy(lambda (a,b,c,d): d)

#when using collect output is sorted
#[(12, 13, 14, 1), (9, 10, 11, 2), (5, 6, 7, 3), (1, 2, 3, 4)]
result.collect

#results are not necessarily sorted in subsequent operations
#[(1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 3), (9, 10, 11, 2), (12, 13, 14, 1)]
result.takeOrdered(5)

#result are sorted when specifying the sort order in takeOrdered
#[(12, 13, 14, 1), (9, 10, 11, 2), (5, 6, 7, 3), (1, 2, 3, 4)]
result.takeOrdered(5,lambda (a,b,c,d): d)
```